# Issues creatingReadStream for google cloud file stored in bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, fs

I'm trying to create a file reader that streams a file so I can then store my data and use it in which ever way I need to. However when I create my read stream I get an error saying that it can't resolve the path bucketName/[object object]. I'm confused as to why it is looking for object object instead of my file name its self. I'm assuming it has something to do with how createReadStream reads a file directly instead of following a path or url. I wasn't able to find any really clear documentation on how it handles working with a file directly. If anyone has any good resources that would be great.

Error log:
Note that familyfilestorage is just the bucketname.

```
ApiError: No such object: familyfilestorage/[object Object]
```

Code:

```
    const filepath = req.params;
    const file = bucket.file(filepath)

    let fileStream = file.createReadStream()
    fileStream.setEncoding('utf8')

    fileStream
        .on('error',(err)=>{
            console.log(err)
            console.log('Log complete')
        })
        .on('end',()=>{
            console.log("Completed")
        })
        .on('data',(chunk)=>{
            console.log(chunk)
        })
```

Comment: you forgot to destructure `req.prarams` , it should be, ```const { filepath } = req.params```

Comment: @bogdanoff That's embarrassing thanks a lot I have no idea why that took so long.